# asp.net mvc: more info on UpdateModel exception

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

i sometimes get an error with the UpdateModel function.
However, i can't seem to locate the exact message which field(s) is/are causing the problem.
For example this one:
"The model of type 'Enquete' was not successfully updated."

it has an innerexception of NULL, and no further description. Is there a way to find out what is causing the problem?

Michel

EDIT:
i see this in my output window:
"A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Web.Mvc.dll"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a wild guess: You are trying to bind `null` to a value type. Check in your model for `int`, `float`, `DateTime`, `structs`, ... data types that you try to bind to `null`.

Comment: i'll look into that, InvalidOperationException does give me a hint that way, you're right. So when i want to be absolutely sure there is no error i have to create a very 'loose' or 'forgiving' model in which you can place any data, and then validate that model and THEN i put it in my business model. Because when the user enters an empty value for a non-nullable int it raises an exception for UpdateModel(). This leaves me with an annoying update from the viewmodel to the businesmodel...

Answer (score 2):

Steve Sanderson has a [wonderful article](http://blog.codeville.net/2009/02/03/using-the-aspnet-mvc-source-code-to-debug-your-app/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+SteveCodeville+%28Steve+%40+Codeville%29) on using the MVC source to help you debug your application.

I think this will help you get more info.

Kindness,

Dan

Comment: that indeed worked, but debugging the mvc source is not an easy thing (well, debugging is, but understanding it is another story)

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this type of exception and from my experience i got what was causing it...
We have one primary key field or identity field in the entity...
If we try to display that field in the view using html control like text box and all then at that time updateModel throws exception
otherwise it wont throw exception

Answer (score 0):

Use TryUpdateModel instead. It won't throw exception, but then you can inspect ModelState for errors.
I know it is late but to help others.